# Implementing Google NoCaptcha ReCaptcha into existing form

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement Googles nocaptcha into my contact form.  I can put the widget in my code fine.  But I don't know how to set up the PHP side (I have no clue with PHP).

I'm wondering if anyone can help me make sense of what to put where...I've tried some tutorials, but again - I barely understand the syntax of my PHP form.

As of right now I have the widget in the form.  Anyone care to help me add the PHP verification?

Thanks.

Code:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['first-name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['last-name'])  ||   
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['phone']) ||
   empty($_POST['location']) ||
   empty($_POST['kw']) ||
   empty($_POST['pv-type']) ||
   empty($_POST['message'])) 

{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$first_name = $_POST['first-name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last-name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$kw = $_POST['kw'];
$pv_type = $_POST['pv-type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Inquiry from: $first_name $last_name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new inquiry from:".
    "\n Name: $first_name $last_name \n Email: $email_address \n Phone Number: $phone  
     \n I have a project in: $location \n The project type is: $pv_type  \n The estimated project size is: $kw
     \n Message: $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: thankyou.html');
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, The way it works is you have to put a div tag in your HTML with a specific class that GOogle uses to generate the noCaptcha test. However, by looking at your PHP code there, you will probably want to do some other things to protect your forms from being abused.

You need to get two API keys from Google that your code will use to communicate with Google. On is used in the HTML form and the other is used on the server in the PHP code.

Here is the basic flow of how it works:
1) Your form has a field on it that includes one of your Google keys (the site key) and Google adds the test to your page when it loads.
2) When a user clicks the checkbox, Google gets the site key to make sure it is your site
3) The user completes the test
4) Google adds another element to your form that has a response token in it
5) When your user submits the form to your website, your PHP code grabs the response token and sends it to Google to be verified.
6) Google then sends your server back another response in JSON format letting you know if the response token was verified. If it was, you go ahead with the next step, if not your show the user an error because something is not right.

That is a rough overview of the process, but I hope it clarifies things for you.